# Getting value from MySQL, and putting them into other table (multiple values at once)

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.6

First and formost, yes i know PHP5.6 is deprecated version, but i want to stick with it and fully learn PHP for myself, before updating to MySQLi.

I'm trying to make a text based game running MySQL and PHP, and currently trying to create a system that:

1.Gets information from user table, username and total actions done (+)

2.At the certain timestamps save all usernames and actions into separete table (-)

3.Resets actions column to 0 for ALL players. (+/- planning to use a mysql trigger and/or cron-job)

My questions:

2) How would you suggest me to insert usernames into seperate table? (only idea i come up is to explode array somehow get variables and sumbit to mysql, question is how to do so? )

3) regarding this number 3, would you suggest something else then triggers or cron-jobs?

Code example bellow

```
<?php
include './config/connect-db.php';
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE actions > 100 ORDER BY 
actions DESC LIMIT 5");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if ($row['u_dmisijos'] >= 100) {
    echo '<li>'.$row["u_name"].' ('.$row["actions"].')<br>';
 }  // if actions
} //while loop
?>
```

EDIT:
MySQL includes a lot of columns, there are only 2 specific I'm focusing on, u_name (username) and actions (actions).

EDIT2:
What i am expecting on second table: ID (AI), username of player with the most action points,  username of player with second action points etc. And Datastamp.

expected SQL
ID, nr1, nr2, nr3, nr4, nr5, Datastamp.

Cheers!

Comment: Why learn something that is going to be incorrect in the future? All `mysql_` functions are gone, learning them at this point is a waste of your time. `mysqli` is available in 5.6 as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that does not help. with the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work or not as I have not tested it. But, I hope you might get a general idea.

```
 <?php 

    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    if (!mysql_select_db("mydbname")) {
        echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE actions > 100 ORDER BY actions DESC LIMIT 5";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
        exit;
    }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $q = "INSERT INTO `new_table` (`u_name`, `actions`) VALUES 
                ($row['u_name'],$row['actions'] )";

        mysql_query($q);

    }

    ?>
```

Regarding resetting all actions to `0` you can create a functions like:

```
function resetActions(){
    //update actions to 0
    $q = "UPDATE table_name SET actions = 0";
    mysql_query($q);
}
```

Now, whenever you need to reset it you can call this function. Or you can call this function in cron job as you required.

Comment: Super thanks for your answer. Inserting code into other table doesnt work, it gives no errors, but it doesnt but anything into table itself (yes i configured connections and even separated fixed variables inside SQL for it to even work.).

Reset code works amazing! Thank you again for this :)

Comment: I don't get it. Did you solve inserting into new table or not? What you tried and what is your error?

Comment: I did not solve the problem. Code still doesn't put any informasion into the new table. I tried to modifying the names by the table i had, and separating variables out from SQL (".$var.") , else im getting syntax error, unexpected ".

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` place this code at top of `connect-db.php` and let me know what is the error. Also, don't forget to show your insert code

Comment: I'm running your raw script, just with changed connections to database. I'm not using include inside that file. After placing the code, nothing changes, no errors apear, and nothing is added into database.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` place this code at `connect-db.php` or top of file.

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/cmgAQL9p) This is how code looks now. Still no error message, still now inserts into database. EDIT: Link to pastebin